# CakePHP 2.0.3 Model validate data issue

Tags: validation, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-model

ok i have some validate issue because i am using in my Form other names then they are in the Table as example:

```
<?=$this->Form->input('name') ?>
```

and in my database table i have something like this named `xyc_name`

every time before i save my data i set them to let know the model what it schould do with the request data but  the validation may do not know where to give the message back or something.

what should i do to put out the validated error message?

this ar my codes:

View:

```
    <?=$this->Session->flash(); ?>
<? 
    $subkat = '';
    foreach($catList as $cat) {
        if($cat['Category']['xyc_parent']!=0) {
            $subkat = '-';
        }else{
            $subkat = '';
        }
            $options[$cat['Category']['xyc_id']] = $subkat.$cat['Category']['xyc_name'];
    } 
?>
<?=$this->Form->create('Product', array('type'=>'file')) ?>

<?=$this->Form->input('category_id', array(
    'label'=>'Kategorie',
    'options' => array($options)
)); ?>
<?=$this->Form->input('payment', array(
    'type'=>'radio',
    'options' => array(1=>'PayPal',2=>'Überweisung',3=>'Barzahlung',4=>'Abholung')
)); ?>
<?=$this->Form->input('Product.name', array('label'=>'Produktname')); ?>
<label for="descr">Beschreibung</label><?=$this->Form->textarea('Product.description', array('id'=>'descr')); ?>
<?=$this->Form->input('Product.price', array('label'=>'Preis von')) ?>
<?=$this->Form->input('Product.price_2', array('label'=>'bis')) ?>
<?=$this->Form->input('Product.quantity', array('label'=>'Anzahl der Artikel')) ?>
<?=$this->Form->input('Product.quantity_price', array('label'=>'Gesamtmengenpreis von')) ?>
<?=$this->Form->input('Product.quantity_price_2', array('label'=>'bis')) ?>
<?=$this->Form->input('Product.uvp', array('label'=>'UVP')) ?>
<?=$this->Form->input('Product.shipment',array('label'=>'Versandart')); ?>
<?=$this->Form->input('Product.shipmentprice',array('label'=>'Versandpreis')); ?>
<?=$this->Form->input('Product.articelcondition',array('label'=>'Artikelzustand')); ?>

<?=$this->Form->end(__('Senden')); ?>
```

Controller:

```
<?php                            
$this->Product->create();

$this->Product->set(array(


 'fatcms_category_id' => $this->request->data['Product']['category_id'],
    $this->userPrefix.'user_id' => $this->userLoggedIn['fatcms_auth_user_id'],
    $this->productPrefix.'name' => $this->request->data['Product']['name'],
    $this->productPrefix.'payment' => $this->request->data['Product']['payment'],
    $this->productPrefix.'description' => $this->request->data['Product']['description'],
    $this->productPrefix.'price' => $this->request->data['Product']['price'],
    $this->productPrefix.'price_2' => $this->request->data['Product']['price_2'],
    $this->productPrefix.'quantity' => $this->request->data['Product']['quantity'],
    $this->productPrefix.'quantity_price' => $this->request->data['Product']['quantity_price'],
    $this->productPrefix.'quantity_price_2' => $this->request->data['Product']['quantity_price_2'],
    $this->productPrefix.'shipment' => $this->request->data['Product']['shipment'],
    $this->productPrefix.'shipmentprice' => $this->request->data['Product']['shipmentprice'],
    $this->productPrefix.'articelcondition' => $this->request->data['Product']['articelcondition'],
    $this->productPrefix.'created' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
    $this->productPrefix.'uvp' => $this->request->data['Product']['uvp']
));

if($this->Product->save()) {

   //CakeSession::write('productid', $this->Product->id);
   $this->redirect('/products/addimg/'.$this->Product->id);

}
?>
```

Model:

```
<?php

    class Product extends AppModel {

            public $name       = 'Product';

            public $useTable   = 'product';

            public $primaryKey = 'xyc_id';

            public $hasMany = array('Productimage'=>array(

                'className'=>'Productimage',
                'foreignKey'=>'xyc_id'

            ));

            public $validate    = array(    

                'xyc_name' => array(    
                    'rule'=>'notEmpty',
                    'message'=>'test'
                ),

                'xyc__description' => 'notEmpty',

                'xyc_uvp' => 'notEmpty',

                'xyc_price' => 'notEmpty',

                'xyc_price_2' => 'notEmpty',


                'xyc_quantity_price_1' => 'notEmpty',

                'xyc_quantity_price_2' => 'notEmpty',

                'xyc_payment' => 'notEmpty',

                'xyc_shipment' => 'notEmpty',

                'xyc_shipmentprice' => 'notEmpty',

                'xyc_articelcondition' => 'notEmpty',

            );


    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

ok i found a solution. because the modul validate the seted data in the controller and also do output with the data which was setted and not the values which was setted in the form.

And therfore the Formhelper of input to put message out have no effect. Therfore you have to define it.

like this:

```
<?
if ($this->Form->isFieldError('prefix_price')) {
    echo $this->Form->error('prefix_price');
}
?>
<?=$this->Form->input('Product.price', array('label'=>'Preis von')) ?>
```

then you got the message which you put in your model for validating